# Problem with `summarise()` input `Illinois` in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Doing an assignment for school in which we use a pre-loaded dataframe (Midwest) from dplyr to manipulate data and display visualizations through shiny.

I'm getting the error "Problem with 'summarise()' input 'Illinois' because "object 'IL' not found (even though that's a variable in a column that I thought I had grouped by.

Here's some of my code at the moment.

```
bar_chart <- function(midwest) {
data_summary <- midwest %>%
  dplyr::group_by(state) %>%
  summarize("Illinois" = mean(IL, na.rm = TRUE),
            "Minnesota" = mean(MN, na.rm = TRUE),
            "Indiana" = mean(IN, na.rm = TRUE),
            "Ohio" = mean(OH, na.rm = TRUE),
            "Wisconsin" = mean(WN, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: If you grouped by "state" then then is a column called "state", not "IL". You need to use column names, not values in `summarize()`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What exactly is in the `midwest` object?

Comment: What you have there doesn't really make sense, you need to pass `summarize` column names, not factor levels within a column. For example `midwest %>% group_by(state) %>% summarize(poptotal = mean(poptotal))`

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! As @MrFlick indicated, try to always post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That way you will get better answers to your question.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things to understand here. Groups specify a level of aggregation, in this case `state`. That means when we `summarize`, we summarize to that specified level of aggregation. We have a data set with multiple states, so when we group by `state`, that means we'll end up with one row for each state. The result is that you don't have to write a line of code for each state like you did in your provided example.

When we summarize, we need to specify a function which we'll use to summarize (i.e. roll-up) the data, as well as a column to apply it to. In this case you're using `mean`, so I'll use that as well, and we'll find the `mean` of `poptotal` for each state.

Finally, while you can use `recode` to replace factor levels, my little example below uses a `left_join` and R's built in table of state names and abbreviations to add it in - a nice little trick if you had all 50 states.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(midwest)

stateTable <-  data.frame(state.abb, state.name)

midwest %>% group_by(state) %>% 
  summarize(poptotal = mean(poptotal)) %>% 
  left_join(. , stateTable, by = c( "state" = "state.abb"))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  state poptotal state.name
  <chr>    <dbl> <fct>     
1 IL     112065. Illinois  
2 IN      60263. Indiana   
3 MI     111992. Michigan  
4 OH     123263. Ohio      
5 WI      67941. Wisconsin
```